# Javascript Alert on Change Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on a different week on [this URL](http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2015-nfl-predictions/) I want to have a function run.

I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#games').change(function() {
        alert("Change");
    });
});
```

but it is never being called. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What type of element is `games`? `.change()` only applies to inputs, but it looks like it's a DIV on your site.

Comment: $('#games') is a DIV. I don't think DIVs are subject to "change" event. Are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.week').on('click', function() {
      alert('change');
   });
});
```

cause you want to target the thing you are clicking on which is `.week`, not the `#games` div...the div doesnt have a change event. (radio buttons, checkboxes, and dropdowns do though)